# Python PermissionError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: python, runtime-error, anaconda3

Program reads all the files data from the file server shared location and insert data into the database

Here is the code:

```
class MetrologyObserver(object):
def __init__(self, root_path):
    self.root_path = root_path
    self.event_handler = MetrologyEventHandler()
    self.event_observer = Observer()

def run(self):
    self.schedule()
    self.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        self.stop()
    self.event_observer.join()

def start(self):
    self.event_observer.start()

def stop(self):
    self.event_observer.stop()

def schedule(self):
    self.event_observer.schedule(self.event_handler,
                                 self.root_path,
                                 recursive=True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   src_path = r'\\shared folder path'
   MetrologyObserver(src_path).run()
```

Getting following error while executing python program
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 112, in _errcheck_handle
raise ctypes.WinError()
PermissionError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functioning.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klxrv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.  Please include your traceback error as text and not as an image.

Comment: Thank you, it's a long code and I am new to Python.  Let me see  how much code I can copy here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. It works for me.

https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied/

If it doesn't work for you, let me know.  I can provide another solution.

Comment: Issue is fixed, I had a wrong file path in the code. Thank you for your solution, I learned couple of python command.